# Explain how this works?

Tags: java

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a=100; 
        a= a + (a=6); 
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

how the result became 106. How works a=a+(a=6)

Comment: the value of a itself which is 100 + 6 from  (a = 6) by changing the value of a !

Comment: Try a= (a=6) + a
What do you think the result would be?

Comment: This is mentionned in the java specifications (15.7) : "The Java programming language guarantees that the operands of operators appear to be evaluated in a specific evaluation order, namely, from left to right " https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the value of a is initially stored 100. Then the value of a becomes 6 as a = 6 is given in the statement. So when you print it. it will print 106.
What were you expecting ??

Answer (score 1):

```
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a=100; 
        a= a + (a=6); 
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Let's break this down:

```
int a = 100;
```

Value of `a` is now `100`.

The assignment (`=`) operator has **right-to-left** associavity. This means anything on the right side of `=` will be evaluated first.

Let's extract the right part of:

```
a = a + (a = 6);
```

which is:

```
a + (a = 6)
```

This is an expression.
Unlike C/C++ where the order of expression evaluation is undefined, Java expressions are always guaranteed to execute from left to right.
So this is how it works, let's get the left part of the above expression:

```
a
```

This will evaluate to `100` because the value of `a` is 100 resulting in this:

```
100 + (a = 6)
```

Now that the left side of `+` is done, let's get the right part:

```
(a = 6)
```

The confusion stems from this part because we don't expect an assignment expression to have a resultant value. But an assignment expression will always yield the value that has just been assigned to the variable in Java.

For example:

```
int x = 42;
System.out.println((x = 10)); // This will change a to 10 but also prints 10
int y = (x = 88); // This will change x to 88 but it was also yield that value, so y will be 88
```

(*Default assignment operators in languages like Python don't have this behavior. An assignment has no output/resultant value*)
This is like any expression, just like `10+20` yields `30`, `(a = 6)` yields 6 but it also has a side-effect, it updates `a` to  `6`.

So after the second part, the right part of the statement will be:

```
100 + 6 // The additional thing here is a has also been updated to 6
106
```

So, finally, `a = 106`.

Comment: Java Language Specification [15.26.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1-500) tells a different story about assignment: *"First, the left-hand operand is evaluated to produce a variable. ..."*, also check [Operator associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_associativity) i